# Which potions are the most profitable to sell?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I have plenty of potion ingredients and I'm low on cash, so I want to make potions to sell for profit. What are the most profitable potions to make money off?

**EDIT:**
I'm able to craft master level potions, but the best would be a list that contains all potion prices. like [this list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Arro4SyEbmqudGJ1bm41SDVQbnNlVnE3NEhmSjhZeFE#gid=0) for gems.

Comment: Are you able to craft Novice, Journeyman or Master potions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I respec'ed to level 10 in Alchemy and Merchantile for this and here's the numbers I calculated.  In a lot of cases, the cost of a potion is less than the cost of its constituting ingredients.  You can decide for yourself which is more valuable here.

Potions:

```
Potion                                      Cost    Ingredients Cost
Greater Damage Boost                        1251                1550

Master Healing Potion                        969                1329
Master Mana Potion                           969                1329

Master Magebane                              915                1580
Master Experience Booster                    915                1552
Master Freezing Sentinel                     915                1545
Master Magic Amplification                   915                1538
Master Flesh Eater                           915                1526
Master Hardened Shell                        915                1526
Master Mana Sap                              915                1526
Master Frostbite                             915                1524
Master Frostguard                            915                1496
Master Magic Precision                       915                1489
Master Force Potion                          915                1484
Master Burning Sentinel                      915                1482
Master Lightning Sentinel                    915                1482
Master Steeled Curtain                       915                1475
Master Blazing Salve                         915                1461
Master Jeweled Shilelagh                     915                1461
Master Lightning Storm                       915                1461
Master Social Grace                          915                1461
Master Current Stopper                       915                1454
Master Flameguard                            915                1454
Master Precision                             915                1453
Master Piercing Serum                        915                1448
Master Blacksmith's Craft                    915                1419
Master Dispelling Boost                      915                1419
Master Thief's Cunning                       915                1419
Master Tracker's Draught                     915                1419
Master Bleeding Resistance                   915                1418
Master Venomguard                            915                1418
Master Serpent's Venom                       915                1407
Master Slashing Fury                         915                1407
Master Sorcerer's Intelligence               915                1393
Master Alchemist's Art                       915                1383
Master Assassin's Evasion                    915                1383
Master Merchant's Command                    915                1383
Master Warrior's Strength                    915                1339
Master Healing Regeneration                  915                1329
Master Mana Regeneration                     915                1329

Minor Damage Boost                           474                 212

Fate Potion                                  346                5004
Greater Damage Deflection                    346                1463
Greater Phasewalk                            346                1363
Greater Freezing Sentinel                    346                 294
Greater Magebane                             346                 280
Greater Experience Booster                   346                 273
Greater Frostbite                            346                 273
Greater Magic Amplification                  346                 259
Greater Frostguard                           346                 245
Greater Burning Sentinel                     346                 231
Greater Lightning Sentinel                   346                 231
Greater Flesh Eater                          346                 226
Greater Hardened Shell                       346                 226
Greater Mana Sap                             346                 226
Greater Steeled Curtain                      346                 224
Greater Blazing Salve                        346                 210
Greater Lightning Storm                      346                 210
Greater Force Potion                         346                 205
Greater Current Stopper                      346                 203
Greater Flameguard                           346                 203
Greater Magic Precision                      346                 189
Greater Piercing Serum                       346                 187
Greater Jeweled Shilelagh                    346                 182
Greater Social Grace                         346                 182
Greater Bleeding Resistance                  346                 167
Greater Venomguard                           346                 167
Greater Serpent's Venom                      346                 156
Greater Slashing Fury                        346                 156
Greater Precision                            346                 153
Greater Sorcerer's Intelligence              346                 142
Greater Blacksmith's Craft                   346                 140
Greater Dispelling Boost                     346                 140
Greater Thief's Cunning                      346                 140
Greater Tracker's Draught                    346                 140
Greater Alchemist's Art                      346                 104
Greater Assassin's Evasion                   346                 104
Greater Merchant's Command                   346                 104
Greater Warrior's Strength                   346                  88
Greater Healing Potion                       346                  78
Greater Healing Regeneration                 346                  78
Greater Mana Potion                          346                  78
Greater Mana Regeneration                    346                  78

Liquid Seduction                             163                 105

Minor Damage Deflection                      131                 125
Minor Phasewalk                              131                 122

Purification Potion                          101                 118

Minor Magebane                                49                 154
Minor Magic Amplification                     49                 154
Minor Experience Booster                      49                 147
Minor Freezing Sentinel                       49                 147
Minor Frostbite                               49                 147
Minor Steeled Curtain                         49                 147
Minor Flesh Eater                             49                 118
Minor Hardened Shell                          49                 118
Minor Mana Sap                                49                 118
Minor Piercing Serum                          49                 108
Minor Blazing Salve                           49                 105
Minor Burning Sentinel                        49                 105
Minor Current Stopper                         49                 105
Minor Lightning Sentinel                      49                 105
Minor Lightning Storm                         49                 105
Minor Frostguard                              49                  98
Minor Magic Precision                         49                  84
Minor Flameguard                              49                  77
Minor Jeweled Shilelagh                       49                  77
Minor Social Grace                            49                  77
Minor Sorcerer's Intelligence                 49                  76
Minor Bleeding Resistance                     49                  69
Minor Force Potion                            49                  69
Minor Serpent's Venom                         49                  69
Minor Slashing Fury                           49                  69
Minor Venomguard                              49                  69
Minor Precision                               49                  66
Minor Blacksmith's Craft                      49                  56
Minor Dispelling Boost                        49                  56
Minor Thief's Cunning                         49                  56
Minor Tracker's Draught                       49                  56
Minor Warrior's Strength                      49                  40
Minor Alchemist's Art                         49                  38
Minor Assassin's Evasion                      49                  38
Minor Merchant's Command                      49                  38
Minor Healing Potion                          49                  30
Minor Healing Regeneration                    49                  30
Minor Mana Potion                             49                  30
Minor Mana Regeneration                       49                  30
```

Ingredients:

```
Essence of Fate              1251

Edelweiss                      49
Leechwood Bark                 49
Prismere Dust                  49
Scarwood Bark                  49
Seaflax                        49
White Flake                    49
Ysa's Breath                   49

Bloodroot                      28
Eel Petal                      28
Scarab Salts                   28
Sky Blossom                    28
Star Thistle                   28
Tindertwig                     28

Black Cohosh                   10
Cripplespore Caps              10
Embereyes                      10
Sativa Fibers                  10
Scarlet Flowstone              10
Softscrabble Powder            10
```

Here's the [raw data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ar04eyzAuM3TdEdLeFZnNGM4Y0tONldUWVZGM2FzdVE) I used to calculate these numbers.

Comment: On the surface, I think it would be more worthwhile to sell your Essences and just brew Greater potions for selling.  Possibly even sell your ingredients instead of brewing them as they might add up to being more than if they were brewed.